# What is the property used for selecting a date on a datetime picker?

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I'm trying to pull values from a database using a simple select statement and a datetime picker. Can you please help me in how I can do this? the select statement is working in SQL when I enter in a specific date in the query but I want to be able to select the date on a datetimepicker and be able to retrieve data for that specific date.

This is the code so far:

```
Dim command As String = "select CUSORDER.ORDERID, CUSORDER.ORDERDATE, 
CUSORDER.STAFFID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERADD_1 
FROM CUSORDER,CUSTOMER 
WHERE CUSORDER.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID AND 
CUSORDER.ORDERDATE = '" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString & "'"
```

Am I using the correct property and format in order to do this?

Comment: `Value` is right, but you should use a parameterized query instead of converting the date to a string and concatenating your SQL.

Comment: Sorry I am at beginner level of programming so I haven't a clue what any of what you said means? Is it easy?

Comment: @112221: You are building a SQL string yourself which could lead to security issues known as SQL Injection. To get around this easily, it's not hard, read up on using ADO parameterized queries.

Comment: @PaulSasik - It this case, the issue is also that of date formatting as strings. What the web server and SQL server may use can be very different.

Answer (score 1):

You should not concatenate strings to get your sql-query. That can cause [sql-injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) vulnerabilities, localization issue or other problems. You should always parametrize your queries:

```
Dim sql As String = "select CUSORDER.ORDERID, CUSORDER.ORDERDATE, CUSORDER.STAFFID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERADD_1 FROM CUSORDER,CUSTOMER WHERE CUSORDER.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID AND CUSORDER.ORDERDATE = @ORDERDATE"
Using con = New SqlConnection(YourConnectionString)
    Using command = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDERDATE", DateTimePicker1.Value)
        con.Open()
        Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                ' ... '
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Security and other issues are no a problem, it is only for a college project and getting it working is the main priority for me.

Comment: @112221: Even in college you should use safe code which also prevents you from issues like this ;) I assume you have not noticed that this answer also solves your issue since the problem is the date format. I don't pass the string to db but the `datetime`, hence you don't have problem with the format.

Answer (score 0):

Just it if helps, I do the following:

```
Dim dteTemp As Date = DateTimePicker.value 'might help any injection code as the convert will fail.

Dim command As String = "select CUSORDER.ORDERID, CUSORDER.ORDERDATE, CUSORDER.STAFFID,
CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID,  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERADD_1 FROM CUSORDER,CUSTOMER WHERE
(CUSORDER.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID) AND
(CUSORDER.ORDERDATE = '" & dteTemp.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & "')"
```

The formatting of the date avoids the problem of the PC being in a different date local to the SQL database.